# Get text from a link in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get text from a service on the same server as my webserver. The link is something like this:

```
http://<OwnIPadres>:8080/calc/something?var=that
```

This is my code:

```
 function httpGet(theUrl)
  {
      alert(theUrl);
        var doc = new XMLHttpRequest();
        doc.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (doc.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                alert("text: " + doc.responseText );
                 document.getElementById('ctm').text = doc.responseText;
            }
        }
        doc.open("get", theUrl);
        doc.setRequestHeader("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8");
        doc.send();
  }
```

The url that i print in my first alert is the good one if i test in my browser, it is an html page with a table in it. But the alert of my text is empty? Is it a problem that the text is html?

Comment: document.getElementById('ctm').value = doc.responseText;

Comment: That just places the text in my html. But the alert already shows no text is returned...

Comment: Which alert ? alert("text: " + doc.responseText ); ?

Comment: Yes, alert("text: " + doc.responseText ); only gives "text: " back

Comment: That only means that your response doesn't have anything!

Comment: theUrl copy this and load in your browser and check its empty or not

Comment: thx for the responses. As said in my post i tested theUrl and i get a html page with a table in it.
@harsha: Yes that is my problem

Comment: Just a curious question... what browser are you running?

Comment: Tried it in firefox 25.0 and chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, its quite ok that your 'text' is 'html'. The problem is that using a different port counts as cross-site scripting. Therefore, your XMLHttpRequest is being stopped by the browser before it actually reaches your page across port 8080.

I'm not sure what else you're doing before and around this code snippet, but you could try an iframe call to your url to get your data, or you could add an

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://:8080/

in your header (however that will only get you the most modern browsers).

Finally, you could pull in a JS framework like JQuery which could help you with pulling in this service data.